# Bundle install error when installing bcrypt-ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Everything was working well, until I ran `bundle install` command, after doing Update from the server (the files updated didn't have anything to do with Gemfile, or anything related to gems), using SVN.

NOTE: I'm running Ruby 1.8.7-p358, and I've been running it for months, on this project, without any problems.

The error I'm getting when I run that command is the following:

```
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:128: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/brian/Projects/DB'
Makefile:122: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/brian/Projects/DB'
gcc -I. -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c crypt_blowfish.c
gcc -I. -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c wrapper.c
gcc -I. -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c crypt_gensalt.c
gcc -I. -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c crypt.c
gcc -I. -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c bcrypt_ext.c
gcc -shared -o bcrypt_ext.so crypt_blowfish.o wrapper.o crypt_gensalt.o crypt.o bcrypt_ext.o -L. -L/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -Wl,-R/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -L/home/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib -lruby  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc

make install
Makefile:128: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/brian/Projects/DB'
Makefile:122: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/brian/Projects/DB'
mkdir -p /home/brian/Projects/DB
mkdir -p Soft/ClienteHabitue/Commerce/src/commerce/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 bcrypt_ext.so /home/brian/Projects/DB Soft/ClienteHabitue/Commerce/src/commerce/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `/home/brian/Projects/DB'
make: *** [Soft/ClienteHabitue/Commerce/src/commerce/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/brian/Projects/DB Soft/ClienteHabitue/Commerce/src/commerce/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/brian/Projects/DB Soft/ClienteHabitue/Commerce/src/commerce/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've googled and also tried to search in forums, but I didn't find an answer that actually works for me.

Could anybody tell me what's going on and how to solve it, please?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` provide in the way of errors?

Comment: Nothing. It installs without a problem, but bundle install command keeps failing...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't installed dev kit. You need to install development kit for ruby first then install Bcrypt ruby gem.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Comment: It seems that I was already installed, because when I run that command I get the following: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby1.8-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.

Comment: maybe you need to reinstall rvm then install ruby1.8-dev package and then install bcrypt ruby

Comment: Well, it seems that the problem was something related to the app path, which contained a space in a part of it. The weird thing is why I was having this problem now, and not through all of this time (6 months) I've been working on this app. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes you are right... i was just commenting this out but i got stuck in coding then haven't remembered..